# segmentation fault in simple string manipulation

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

This program is giving segmentation fault on execution. How do I fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int bufsize = 1024;
  char *buf;
  char *msg="GET /dumprequest HTTP/1.1";
  memset (buf,0, bufsize);
  strcpy(buf,msg);
  puts(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: problem solved.....  i was trying to change a constant..

Answer (score 6):

You have no memory allocated for `buf`. Try:

```
const int bufsize = 1024;
char buf[bufsize];
```

Answer (score 1):

The calls to `memset()` and `strcpy()` are trying to write to a pointer that is pointing to a random location rather than a `malloc()`ed block of memory, and that will certainly cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some memory for buf.

Such as

```
buf = (char *) malloc (bufsize);
```

And when you're finished:

```
free (buf);
```

Or make it a char array.

Answer (score -1):

Using gcc on Ubuntu 10.10 the above code works.

malloc() and free() could be used to allocate some memory.
free() being called at the end of the function.

```
buf = (char *) malloc (bufsize);
```

This will allocate memory of the size 1024 for the buf.

Comment: It doesn't work. It may seem to work. But code invoking UB is broken, period.

Comment: That's why I suggested the malloc().